# how to put bold for certain word in textfield?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have for writing essay in the report. I just want to bold some text in my verse. I have put `<b></b>` tag in text, but it does not work.

An example of what I want is "My first name is **Jason** and my last name is **Michael**". Anybody know about this?

Comment: Mark and Androdos solutions worked for me in Jasper Studio 5.6. I couldn't have styles working in the pdf export when using html tags.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try surrounding the words you want to highlight with HTML `<b></b>` (bold) tags, and change the markup attribute of textfield to HTML.

PS: if you have some difficulties seeing Bold, try to set Textfield font to Arial.

Comment: You would do so by adding markup="html" in the textElement tag like <textElement markup="html">

Answer (score 16):

This work good:

```
"<style isBold='true' pdfFontName='Helvetica-Bold'>" + $F{data} + "</style>"
```

for input data from datasource, or

```
<style isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold">Bolt text</style>
```

only for some static text.

For Text-field set properties **Markup** = styled.

Comment: thanks for the additional rememberance below as markup= styled.

Answer (score 6):

I just changed Properties → Markup → HTML. It works.

Answer (score 4):

The `<b> </b>` tags no longer work on text fields.  Make sure that 'Styled text' is enabled for the text field and put this in the field expression.

`<style isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold">Text to be bold...</style>`

The pdfFontName can be whatever you like.

If you are making text bold that is already in a string be sure to escape the above quotes with a backslash or use single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

As an example, one of my expressions:
{

```
"<b>"+$F{bezeichnung}+"</b>"+" ("+$F{anzahlStimmen}+" "+$R{stimmenI18N}+")"
```

}

Answer (score 0):

For example - first character of the word is **RED**

```
        <textField pattern="">
            <reportElement x="23" y="35" width="189" height="18" forecolor="#000000" uuid="dd8bc5b3-1dc9-4348-84c8-ff7993746830"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="styled">
                <font fontName="Apolonia" size="17" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["<style forecolor=\"red\">"+$F{L1_word}.substring(0,1)+"</style>"+$F{L1_word}.substring(1)]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
```

[image: Result]